# How do I follow a specific question on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support

How should one follow specific question?

Many a times, I found interesting question of my interest on Stack Overflow. But sometimes it is not answered and later it becomes difficult to find.

Is there a way so that any updates to questions, or answers or new answers will be notified?

Comment: There is also an app (extension) for that: http://stackapps.com/q/4454/27903  It will give you notices for comments and answers posted to a question you mark to follow

Comment: `Is there a way so that ...will be notified` yes: the app/extension I linked provides *active* notifications

Comment: I don't completely agree with the wording 'duplicate' here. As Narfanar pointed out in a comment below, simply _following_ a question isn't the same as marking them as a _favorite_. However the answer to the linked question does _more or less_ answer this question.

Comment: Should be re-opened and an answer added mentioning the new (beta?) `follow` function. Also, the duplicate is no longer relevant (and arguably never was close enough to be a duplicate).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Click the star below vote counts.

> [image]

Then you can find this question in [your favorites](https://stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=favorites). If any changes occur with this question, a number saying how many changes occurred appears in near the name of this tab ("favorites").

> [image]

When you click this tab, the question(s) which has been changed since you checked you favorites will have  highlighted background.

> [image]

Comment: The answer is technically correct, but a 'favorite' is definitely not always a 'follow', and the same for the other way. Simply the feature is missing on SE right now. A glaring omission, IMHO.